# The var keyword not showing up in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I've installed a new instance of visual studio 2010 premium and everything seems to work fine when I load old projects.  When I start to write new classes though, the var keyword is not working or showing up in intellisense.  This is a new solution and no web project. (so no web.config)  Target framework for the project is set to .net 4.0.  When I try compiling it by writing

```
var x = "this";
```

I get "A get or set accessor expected" error.

Do I need to reinstall?  Any ideas what could be wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Can you check the the Framework version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have parentheses after your method name so the compiler thinks you're defining a property.

```
public void Server_Test()
{
    var ...
}
```

Comment: A typical Friday afternoon 17:00 problem. :)

Comment: Sounds like someone came from VB.NET ;)

Comment: The more general principle here is that IntelliSense tries to not make suggestions that would be illegal programs.

Comment: Compilers are so pedantic. First it requires a get or set accessor. And then when you come up with one, you see that it has tricked you: _error CS0547: 'Server_Test': property or indexer cannot have void type_ (Just joking.)

Comment: @jeppe you're right; the IDE should have melted down as soon as the open curly brace was entered without the parentheses with a message like "You've violated all that is good and holy about C# - you must now reboot as punishment"

Comment: Ugh, silly me, thanks for the obvious answer and my brain shutting down on a basic mistake!